# How to covert javafx project to standalone software?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, installation

I have created a javafx project in intellij idea . Now i want to output it as a standalone software . I want to create an installation version of that project. How to do that in intellij idea?

Answer (score 0):

There is a manual on packaging javafx apps:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html